# ghost files—now you see 'em, now you don't?

Tags: terminal, zsh, path, file-transfer

Ghost files—I don't know what else to call them.

I have an external drive which the system refuses to make writable.  Most of the files on it are already on my internal drive.  To save time and space, I made a list of the files that aren't and wrote a script to create the directories and copy the files.  I included some debugging printouts in the script.

`mkdir -p "~/tempdir/PATH"` gives no error message.

`echo "~/tempdir/PATH"` shows the path is correct

`cp "DISK/PATH/FILE" "~/tempdir/PATH/FILE"` says "DISK/PATH/FILE" doesn't exist, yet

`wc "~/tempdir/PATH/FILE"` shows a reasonable size for the type of file.  But immediately after,

`ls -la "~/tempdir/PATH/FILE"` says no such file or directory and Finder agrees that the top level of PATH is not in tempdir

This inconsistency repeats for every file in the list.  `chmod -RN`, `xattr -rc`, and such were used to ensure it wasn't a permissions issue (even though there were no permission error messages).

I didn't know how to turn off "oh-my-zsh" so I went to bash and the script did what was expected.  So my guess is that "oh-my-zsh" has aliased one or more of the commands to behave very weirdly.

**HOW is it possible in zsh+"oh-my-zsh" for `cp` to say the source doesn't exist, yet `wc` is able to read the destination in a file Finder says isn't there?  And then for `ls` to agree that the destination doesn't exist?**

MacOS 12.5 / zsh with "oh-my-zsh"

Re. the following, the 5TB partition (disk8) appears later in the list with its name.  fsck & Disk Utility & Time Machine have no problem with it.  Any attempt to delete files not needed on 3TB gets "read-only file system".  `sudo mount -w` fails whether or not the volume is mounted.  fsck & Disk Utility show errors that are uncorrected.[image]

UPDATE: in bash, the errors that zsh+"oh-my-zsh" gets on every file do not happen on most files, but still happen on five or ten percent!  (same script)

UPDATE TWO: Even though the error messages are not there for **most** (not all) of the files and paths in bash, `find` says that none of the files are there, and only one of the bottom level directories!

UPDATE 3: I discovered that the shell created a directory called "~" instead of expanding it.  I knew that `$` variables were expanded inside double quotes, but didn't know that `~` isn't.  (I think that inconsistency was a bad design choice, but we're stuck with it now.)  Came here to mention it as a solution and I see that it is already in a comment.  Anyway, that's where my "ghost files" went.

Comment: Have you tried zsh without oh-my-zsh or bash?

Comment: What is the format of the external drive? What do you mean by "the system refuses to make [the external drive] writable"?

Comment: There have been 3rd-party data recovery programs for HFS for ages, and some now for APFS.  And one open source project claims to repair HFS volumes.  I don't get why Apple's fsck still can't correct problems it is able to describe in detail.

Comment: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/11099

Comment: Apple takes a conservative stance. If fsck can’t guarantee a sane directory, it goes read only so you know to use a different tool or save the data with a backup. Do other disks throw file system errors when you repair them from this Mac?

Comment: You shouldn't quote the filename if it begins with `~`, the quotes prevent expanding that to your home directory.

Comment: @WGroleau, I would do what mmmmmm suggested. `.oh-my-zsh` has bugs

Comment: @Barmar, looks like you found the answer before I did.  Feel free to put it in that format.

Comment: Your command `echo :~/tempdir/PATH"` has an unbalanced quote. Is this a typo?

Comment: `mkdir -p "~/tempdir/PATH"` does not give you an error message, because it first creates a directory with the name `~`, under this a directory with the name `tempdir`, and under that finally a directory named `PATH`. If you do a `ls -lr "~"`, you should see this directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is not expanded inside quotes. So take that part of the path out of the quotes. Change.

```
mkdir -p "~/tempdir/PATH"
```

to

```
mkdir -p ~/"tempdir/PATH"
```

Comment: Another alternative is to use `$HOME` instead of `~`.